# Netty4 add HttpChunkAggregator

Tags: java, http, netty

I am writing a HTTP client using Netty 4.

I don't want to handle chunking manually, hence I added the following to my pipeline:

```
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576));
```

However, I am getting the following compilation error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addLast(java.lang.String,org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator)
```

Other handlers like this are not throwing any error.

Any clue on how to resolve this?

I checked the latest example on git, but couldn't find any relevant example. Any good example will also be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be following a `3.x` example, in Netty 4 they changed the package structure from `org.jboss.netty...` to `io.netty...`.

You could use Netty 3.6 to complete you example or switch to using Netty 4 - the [http examples](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http) may be a good starting point.

Incidentally, you can find major changes between the two versions on the [project's wiki](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/New-and-noteworthy).

Comment: Thanks for the reply after going through all the examples I was able to finally figure out that `HttpChunkAggregator` is now replaced with `HttpObjectAggregator`.